# Jax vmap, in_axes doesn't work if keyword argument is passed

Tags: python, jax, xla, google-jax

The parameter `in_axes` in `vmap` seems to only work for positional arguments.
But throws `AssertionError` (with no message) called with keyword argument.

```py
from jax import vmap
import numpy as np

def foo(a, b, c):
    return a * b + c

foo = vmap(foo, in_axes=(0, 0, None))

aj, bj = np.random.rand(2, 100, 1)
foo(aj, bj, 10)  # works
foo(aj, bj, c=10)  # throws error
```

**console**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Amith\PycharmProjects\nntp\venv\lib\site-packages\jax\_src\api_util.py", line 300, in flatten_axes
    tree_map(add_leaves, _replace_nones(proxy, axis_tree), dummy)
  File "C:\Users\Amith\PycharmProjects\nntp\venv\lib\site-packages\jax\_src\tree_util.py", line 183, in tree_map
    all_leaves = [leaves] + [treedef.flatten_up_to(r) for r in rest]
  File "C:\Users\Amith\PycharmProjects\nntp\venv\lib\site-packages\jax\_src\tree_util.py", line 183, in <listcomp>
    all_leaves = [leaves] + [treedef.flatten_up_to(r) for r in rest]
ValueError: Tuple arity mismatch: 2 != 3; tuple: (<object object at 0x00000187F7BF4380>, <object object at 0x00000187F7BF4380>).
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Amith\PycharmProjects\nntp\venv\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3433, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-2-20500a2f8a08>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:\\Users\\Amith\\PycharmProjects\\nntp\\tests\\test2.py', wdir='C:\\Users\\Amith\\PycharmProjects\\nntp\\tests')
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2022.2\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 198, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2022.2\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:\Users\Amith\PycharmProjects\nntp\tests\test2.py", line 11, in <module>
    foo(aj, bj, c=10)
  File "C:\Users\Amith\PycharmProjects\nntp\venv\lib\site-packages\jax\_src\traceback_util.py", line 162, in reraise_with_filtered_traceback
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Amith\PycharmProjects\nntp\venv\lib\site-packages\jax\_src\api.py", line 1481, in vmap_f
    in_axes_flat = flatten_axes("vmap in_axes", in_tree, (in_axes, 0), kws=True)
  File "C:\Users\Amith\PycharmProjects\nntp\venv\lib\site-packages\jax\_src\api_util.py", line 306, in flatten_axes
    assert treedef_is_leaf(leaf)
AssertionError
```

how would one go about running foo as `foo(aj, bj, c=10)` without provoking the error?

Comment: the problem seems to be `ValueError: Tuple arity mismatch: 2 != 3; tuple`, but if make in_axes=(0, 0), c will be mapped which i don't want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's true that `vmap` `in_axes` only works for positional arguments. If you want to make a more general vmapped function, the best option currently is probably to use a wrapper function. For example:

```py
def _foo(a, b, c):
    return a * b + c

def foo(a, b, c):
  return vmap(_foo, in_axes=(0, 0, None))(a, b, c)
```